# How to keep apache running on Windows machine?

Tags: windows, performance, apache-http-server, windows-server-2008, http

I am forced to use Apache on a Windows machine (server 2008) - basically it was installed in the XAMPP package.

The problem is that it frequently hangs up. The "send error" notification appears - and untill I press cancel on it, the Apache is not responding.

Strangely, when I cancel the notification, it resumes working instantly. The only time it seems to be not working is when this prompt is on the screen.

How do I make apache running constantly (ignoring those errors?) Sometimes I am unable to respond to this notification and the Apache server stays unresponsive for few hours.

How would one go about fixing this instability problem? ( Assuming it's impossible to move t other OS/Solution right now ).

Comment: The first step, are you running the current version of Apache, what your experiencing isn't normal.  You need to figure out why the "send error" notifcations are being generated.